# Node js Create Dialogflow Agents under single project

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am currently evaluating means to create multiple Dialogflow agents programmatically. While doing the analysis I tried REST interface released on June 13, 2019, with this interface I am able to edit an existing agent. However, could not create a new one.
Need pointers on below points:

1. Can we create multiple agents under a single project

Comment: i think its only allowed, 1 agent per 1 project

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  From [this page](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-manage):

> Note: You can only create one agent for a GCP project. If you need multiple agents, you will need to create multiple projects.